# phpmyadmin - How to set field values dependant on foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin

How do I setup fields to be dependent on what foreign key is input?

I have googled and searched stack overflow, using similar questions to that, but couldn't find anything that fitted what I was looking for. There are pictures and an example below to better describe what I am asking.

Here's my table (that I want fields to be dependant on there foreign keys):
[image]

`jo_route` is a foreign key for this table:
[image]

and `jo_type` is a foreign key for this table:
[image]
[image]

When I go to insert a record into the journeys table, and select the route id. How do I get the corresponding information from that foreign keys table to appear in the respective fields in this table.

For example, `jo_type` as 3 records (as shown in the picture). The foreign key `jo_type` is linked with this table. Say I select the ID for air (2) in the journeys table. How do I get the related fields (`jo_seats_total`) to be automatically chosen from the travel types table? So it should appear as 100.

Hopefully I have explained my problem well enough.

Thanks in advance for any help!
Sorry for the long post.

Comment: show table structure in text format.

Comment: @denny What do you mean in text format? As in MySQL format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is something that you looking for...

```
SELECT t.tt_max_seat, t.tt_name, r.ro_origin, r.ro_destination, 
j.jo_seats_total, j.jo_seats_take, j.jo_seats_available
FROM journey j
JOIN route r ON j.jo_route = r.ro_id
JOIN type t ON j.jo_type = t.tt_id
WHERE j.jo_type = 2
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand that you've used t, j and r before the attribute names in the SELECT part as the table names. But on the FROM and JOINS sections, what are the letters after journey, route and type?

Comment: j, r and t are the table aliases. So in place of determining column name with table name, its to create aliases and use them in place of table name.

It helps mysql to determine it needs to pick which column from which table. In normal way u can say nick name of table

Comment: I had to change a few things but got that SQL statement to work - however it returned an empty set?